# TCP syn based traffic from our network

Tags: tcp

We have two Debian servers connected to a router which is  part of a public network. One of them is email server based on postfix and dovecote  and rouncube. Second one is DHCP, DNS, Apache,squid3 based system hosting website and distributing internet to 200 computer LAN. we recently received email from ISP with following note.

"we have again observed multiple outgoing tcp syn based suspicious traffic from your institute towards various chinese destination ip's since morning hours. kindly inform the concerned team regarding the same observation so that adequate measures are taken to curb such traffic "

Considering types of users of my LAN, it is impossible to think that my LAN users can deliberately do it.

Can some computer from outside our network mimic tcp syn based suspicious traffic from MY institute?

Can email server with some silly configuration mistake be responsible?

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP is informing you that your computers are originating the traffic then you can rely on it to be true. What you should do is ask for more detail about the offending SYN segments so you can set up a tcpdump session to capture them on your side and find out which of your LAN users is misbehaving.

Comment: My users can Access net only through squid proxy. Sarg and squid log donot show any excess activity from any user. That is why I am thinking in above mentioned two directions.

Comment: The source country is USA, while this server is in india